# reading large lists through stdin in C

Tags: c, list, stdin, bufferedreader

If my program is going to have large lists of numbers passed in through `stdin`, what would be the most efficient way of reading this in?

The input I'm going to be passing into the program is going to be of the following format:

```
3,5;6,7;8,9;11,4;;
```

I need to process the input so that I can use the numbers between the colons (i.e I want to be able to use 3 and 5, 6 and 7 etc etc). The `;;` indicates that it is the end of the line.

I was thinking of using a buffered reader to read entire lines and then using parseInt.

Would this be the most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: you should probably change you tags to C and stdin

Comment: oh woops sorry accident, I was looking at ways of doing this in java and must have accidentally put it down

Comment: How long is the longest input line?

Comment: Well the way that the input is passed into stdin is going to be through a file and all I know is that the max size of that file could be upwards of 70mb. Sorry if that doesn't help

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. I was going to suggest reading a line at time, but it doesn't work if the line length is unlimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other fairly elegant way to handle this is to allow `strtol` to parse the input by advancing the string to be read to `endptr` as returned by `strtol`. Combined with an array allocated/reallocated as needed, you should be able to handle lines of any length (up to memory exhaustion). The example below uses a single array for the data. If you want to store multiple lines, each as a separate array, you can use the same approach, but start with a pointer to array of pointers to int. (i.e. `int **numbers` and allocate the pointers and then each array). Let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define NMAX 256

int main () {

    char *ln = NULL;                /* NULL forces getline to allocate  */
    size_t n = 0;                   /* max chars to read (0 - no limit) */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;               /* number of chars actually read    */
    int *numbers = NULL;            /* array to hold numbers            */
    size_t nmax = NMAX;             /* check for reallocation           */
    size_t idx = 0;                 /* numbers array index              */

    if (!(numbers = calloc (NMAX, sizeof *numbers))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line from stdin - dynamicallly allocated   */
    while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        char *p = ln;       /* pointer for use with strtol  */
        char *ep = NULL;

        errno = 0;
        while (errno == 0)
        {
            /* parse/convert each number on stdin   */ 
            numbers[idx] = strtol (p, &ep, 10);
            /* note: overflow/underflow checks omitted */
            /* if valid conversion to number */
            if (errno == 0 && p != ep)
            {
                idx++;              /* increment index      */
                if (!ep) break;     /* check for end of str */
            }

            /* skip delimiters/move pointer to next digit   */
            while (*ep && (*ep <= '0' || *ep >= '9')) ep++;
            if (*ep) 
                p = ep;
            else 
                break;

            /* reallocate numbers if idx = nmax */
            if (idx == nmax)
            {
                int *tmp = realloc (numbers, 2 * nmax * sizeof *numbers);
                if (!tmp) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "Error: struct reallocation failure.\n");
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                numbers = tmp;
                memset (numbers + nmax, 0, nmax * sizeof *numbers);
                nmax *= 2;
            }
        }
    }

    /* free mem allocated by getline */
    if (ln) free (ln);

    /* show values stored in array   */
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf (" numbers[%2zu]  %d\n", i, numbers[i]);

    /* free mem allocate to numbers  */
    if (numbers) free (numbers);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ echo "3,5;6,7;8,9;11,4;;" | ./bin/prsistdin
 numbers[ 0]  3
 numbers[ 1]  5
 numbers[ 2]  6
 numbers[ 3]  7
 numbers[ 4]  8
 numbers[ 5]  11
 numbers[ 6]  4
```

**Also works where the string is stored in a file as:**

```
$ cat dat/numsemic.csv | ./bin/prsistdin
or
$ ./bin/prsistdin < dat/numsemic.csv
```

---

### Using `fgets` and without `size_t`

It took a little reworking to come up with a revision I was happy with that eliminated `getline` and substituted `fgets`. `getline` is far more flexible, handling the allocation of space for you, with `fgets` it is up to you. (not to mention `getline` returning the actual number of chars read without having to call `strlen`).

My goal here was to preserve the ability to read any length line to meet your requirement. That either meant initially allocating some huge line buffer (wasteful) or coming up with a scheme that would reallocate the input line buffer as needed in the event it was longer than the space initially allocate to `ln`. (this is what `getline` does so well). I'm reasonably happy with the results. **Note:** I put the reallocation code in functions to keep `main` reasonably clean. **footnote 2**

Take a look at the following code. Note, I have left the `DEBUG` preprocessor directives in the code allowing you to compile with the `-DDEBUG` flag if you want to have it spit out each time it allocates. **[footnote 1]** You can compile the code with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o yourexename yourfilename.c
```

or if you want the debugging output (e.g. set LMAX to `2` or something less than the line length), use the following:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o yourexename yourfilename.c -DDEBUG
```

Let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define NMAX 256
#define LMAX 1024

char *realloc_char (char *sp, unsigned int *n); /* reallocate char array    */
int *realloc_int (int *sp, unsigned int *n);    /* reallocate int array     */
char *fixshortread (FILE *fp, char **s, unsigned int *n); /* read all stdin */

int main () {

    char *ln = NULL;                    /* dynamically allocated for fgets  */
    int *numbers = NULL;                /* array to hold numbers            */
    unsigned int nmax = NMAX;           /* numbers check for reallocation   */
    unsigned int lmax = LMAX;           /* ln check for reallocation        */
    unsigned int idx = 0;               /* numbers array index              */
    unsigned int i = 0;                 /* simple counter variable          */
    char *nl = NULL;

    /* initial allocation for numbers */
    if (!(numbers = calloc (NMAX, sizeof *numbers))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed (numbers).");
        return 1;
    }

    /* initial allocation for ln */
    if (!(ln = calloc (LMAX, sizeof *ln))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed (ln).");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line from stdin - dynamicallly allocated   */
    while (fgets (ln, lmax, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        /* provide a fallback to read remainder of line
        if the line length exceeds lmax */
        if (!(nl = strchr (ln, '\n')))
            fixshortread (stdin, &ln, &lmax); 
        else
            *nl = 0;

        char *p = ln;       /* pointer for use with strtol  */
        char *ep = NULL;

        errno = 0;
        while (errno == 0)
        {
            /* parse/convert each number on stdin   */
            numbers[idx] = strtol (p, &ep, 10);
            /* note: overflow/underflow checks omitted */
            /* if valid conversion to number */
            if (errno == 0 && p != ep)
            {
                idx++;              /* increment index      */
                if (!ep) break;     /* check for end of str */
            }

            /* skip delimiters/move pointer to next digit   */
            while (*ep && (*ep <= '0' || *ep >= '9')) ep++;
            if (*ep)
                p = ep;
            else
                break;

            /* reallocate numbers if idx = nmax */
            if (idx == nmax)
                realloc_int (numbers, &nmax);
        }
    }

    /* free mem allocated by getline */
    if (ln) free (ln);

    /* show values stored in array   */
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf (" numbers[%2u]  %d\n", (unsigned int)i, numbers[i]);

    /* free mem allocate to numbers  */
    if (numbers) free (numbers);

    return 0;
}

/* reallocate character pointer memory */
char *realloc_char (char *sp, unsigned int *n)
{
    char *tmp = realloc (sp, 2 * *n * sizeof *sp);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf ("\n  reallocating %u to %u\n", *n, *n * 2);
#endif
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: char pointer reallocation failure.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sp = tmp;
    memset (sp + *n, 0, *n * sizeof *sp); /* memset new ptrs 0 */
    *n *= 2;

    return sp;
}

/* reallocate integer pointer memory */
int *realloc_int (int *sp, unsigned int *n)
{
    int *tmp = realloc (sp, 2 * *n * sizeof *sp);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf ("\n  reallocating %u to %u\n", *n, *n * 2);
#endif
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: int pointer reallocation failure.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sp = tmp;
    memset (sp + *n, 0, *n * sizeof *sp); /* memset new ptrs 0 */
    *n *= 2;

    return sp;
}

/* if fgets fails to read entire line, fix short read */
char *fixshortread (FILE *fp, char **s, unsigned int *n)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    int c = 0;

    i = *n - 1;
    realloc_char (*s, n);
    do
    {
        c = fgetc (fp);
        (*s)[i] = c;
        i++;
        if (i == *n)
            realloc_char (*s, n);
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
    (*s)[i-1] = 0;

    return *s;
}
```

**footnote 1**

nothing special about the choice of the word `DEBUG` (it could have been `DOG`, etc..), the point to take away is if you want to conditionally include/exclude code, you can simply use preprocessor flags to do that. You just add `-Dflagname` to pass `flagname` to the compiler.

**footnote 2**

you can combine the reallocation functions into a single `void*` function that accepts a void pointer as its argument along with the `size` of the type to be reallocated and returns a void pointer to the reallocated space -- but we will leave that for a later date.

Comment: I'm quite new at programming in C, so this solution kinda went over my head. Would you be able to suggest a simpler solution than this one? It's not a problem if the simpler solution isn't as fast

Comment: also, what does int main() mean? I'm familiar with int main(void)

Comment: `int main()` is the entry point for execution of the code. (where the computer starts running your program). As far as a simpler solution, there are just different functions that can be used, etc.. , none really 'simpler' than the other. You requirement specified potential for **long** lines and file sizes upwards of `70 Meg`. You really cannot provide the flexibility needed to handle that with static variable declaration. Take the time to understand what the code does -- it is all part of learning C. Don't expect to just look at it and understand it, it takes looking each piece up.

Comment: I want to change the input for testing purposes so that it is received from a file. Would I just change this line `while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, stdin)) != -1)` to `while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, fp)) != -1)` ?

Comment: Also, I get an error when I try and compile the program. The error is `size_t : illegal use of this type as an expression.` What would be the issue?

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o parsestdin parsestdin.c` -- no errors, no warnings. What compiler are you using? If your compiler doesn't support `size_t`, just make them `unsigned int`.

Comment: I changed them to unsigned int and the errors have gone away but now I get another error saying "unresolved external symbol _getline referenced in function main"

Comment: You can leave the `getline` variables `n` and `nchr` as `size_t` (that is what `getline` requires)

Comment: what do you mean leave them?

Comment: Here, let me do a `fgets` version. `VS2013` is **NOT** standards compliant. (thanks MS). Hold on I'll fix mickey soft's problem...

Comment: What was the issue with it?

Comment: It is not entirely their fault, but a good part of it is. MS does not update always their compiler to reflect current standards. Combine the with `getline` not always being portable and it becomes a guessing game. You may check and you may be able to add `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the beginning to help with the issue, but I'm not familiar enough with VS2013 to know for sure. Regardless, I re-wrote the code for `fgets` and eliminated `size_t`, so give it a try as well.

Comment: I'm wondering why you didn't use strtok() to achieve the same functionality that you got when you skipped the delimiters using pointers? Wouldn't this have saved space and you wouldn't have as much code?

Comment: also, can you please explain what `memset (sp + *n, 0, *n * sizeof *sp);` and `*n *= 2;` do?

Comment: During `realloc` the new memory is NOT initialized to `0`. To make sure it is, I use `memset`. The line says use `memset` to fill with `nmax * sizeof (int)` zeros starting at `sp + *n` (that's the first byte after the old data). Then `0` says fill it with zeros (null), not char value for `'0'`. Next `*n * sizeof *sp)` says fill it with this many zeros. Recall `&nmax` was passed to the function as int pointer `n`. Dereferencing with `*n` just gives `nmax`, and `sizeof *sp` is just `sizeof (int)`. So you fill the new mem with `nmax * sizeof (int)` zeros. Setting zero lets you test if filled.

Answer (score 3):

**This is a working solution**

One way to do this is to use strtok() and store the values in an array. Ideally, dynamically allocated.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int lst_size=100;
    int line_size=255;

    int lst[lst_size];
    int count=0;

    char buff[line_size];
    char * token=NULL;
    fgets (buff, line_size, stdin); //Get input
```

Using strtok by passing ',' and ';' as deleminator.

```
    token=strtok(buff, ";,");
    lst[count++]=atoi(token); 
    while(token=strtok(NULL, ";,")){
          lst[count++]=atoi(token);
    }
```

Finally you have to account for the double ";;" by reducing the count by 1, because atoi(token) will return 0 for that case and store it in the nth index. Which you don't want.

```
  count--;

}
```

Comment: The list could be of unlimited size

Comment: Yes, this will still work. You can use a linked list or a vector to store the values

Comment: Could you please explain what the while loop is doing?

Comment: To understand this, you will need to understand the functionality of strtok(). So, suppose the string is, `"string=abc,4,32,44444"` and you call the strtok(). This first call `strtok(string,",")` NOTE: Separated by "comma" ----> will return [ABC]. The next call  `strtok(NULL, ",")` will return [4]. The next call `strtok(NULL, ",")` will return  [32]....and so on until there is no more values to return. When calling strtok() for such a purpose, you first pass the string as the parameter. The subsequent calls, you pass NULL. Read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: Strtok() can also accept more than one deliminator. So for your example, you could pass `strtok(string, "{comma}{semicolon}")`

Comment: Ok, I understand that now. The next problem is that the size of the line could be greater than what you've initialised. How to get past this?

Comment: Also, if i wanted to test a small input which isn't passed in through stdin, how would the code need to be modified to suit this purpose?

Comment: what if I want to store the input through dynamic memory allocation?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little rusty at C, but could this work for you?

```
char[1000] remainder;
int first, second;
fp = fopen("C:\\file.txt", "r"); // Error check this, probably.
while (fgets(&remainder, 1000, fp) != null) { // Get a line.
    while (sscanf(remainder, "%d,%d;%s", first, second, remainder) != null) {
        // place first and second into a struct or something
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the general idea of it could, but I'm pretty sure that using sscanf isn't as fast? If the input is going to be massive then I would assume that it would take fairly long to execute.

Comment: Yeah, I agree @cp101020304. Thought you were working with a string a few hundred characters long. Try this solution?

Comment: @cp101020304: if the input is massive, *anything* will take a while, but `fscanf` should be as fast as anything.

Comment: I made it so it scans through each line (as I missed that when I read your question)

Comment: The file pointer line isn't necessary because the input is going to be fed into stdin through a file anyway so the program should just start processing the input without needing to open any input files. I hope that made sense and sorry for the vagueness/misunderstanding regarding the wording of the question :)

Comment: @rici is there any way to implement a buffered reader in C? I would assume that this would be faster than scanf?

Comment: @cp101020304: Why would you assume that? C input streams are buffered, so scanf reads from the buffer.

Comment: oh! I wasn't aware that the C input streams were buffered. In that case, I might try this solution!

Comment: The solution work out for you? Hopefully didn't require too many modifications =)

Comment: This question was only a small portion of the problem I had so I'm still writing the code to solve it but I will definitely report back once I get a result :)

Comment: I'm currently trying to implement this solution, but have a few concerns. Is there any other way of doing this dynamically instead of preallocating the remainder array at the start? I ask this because I am not sure how long an input line is going to be (it could be even greater than 1000) so I don't want any invalid array access.

Comment: Whenever I try and run this code, the program crashes and I can't figure out why :/

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is read in from *stdin* using **[fgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)** or **fgetc**.  You could also use **[getline()](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html)** since you're reading in from stdin.

Once you read in the line you can use **[strtok()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)** with the delimiter for ";" to split the string into pieces at the semicolons.  You can loop through until strok() is null, or in this case, ';'.  Also in C you should use **[atoi()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)** to convert strings to integers.

For Example:

```
int length = 256;
char* str = (char*)malloc(length);
int err = getline(&str, &length, stdin);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would read in the command args, then parse using the `strtok()` library method

`http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html`

(The web page referenced by the URL above even has a code sample of how to use it.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take note that it is generally not acceptable to answer a question by directing the user to an outside link. StackOverflow is a learning site not only for the questioner, but for anyone in the future with a similar question. There is no guarantee that the link provide will be valid in the future which will render your answer meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar_unlocked()` is what you are looking for.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline int fastRead_int(int * x)
{
  register int c = getchar_unlocked();
  *x = 0;

  // clean stuff in front of + look for EOF
  for(; ((c<48 || c>57) && c != EOF); c = getchar_unlocked());
  if(c == EOF)
    return 0;

  // build int
  for(; c>47 && c<58 ; c = getchar_unlocked()) {
    *x = (*x<<1) + (*x<<3) + c - 48;
  }
  return 1;
}

int main()
{
  int x;
  while(fastRead_int(&x))
    printf("%d ",x);
  return 0;
}
```

For input `1;2;2;;3;;4;;;;;54;;;;` the code above produces `1 2 2 3 4 54`.

I guarantee, this solution is a lot faster than others presented in this topic. It is not only using `getchar_unlocked()`, but also uses `register`, `inline` as well as multiplying by 10 tricky way: `(*x<<1) + (*x<<3)`.

I wish you good luck in finding better solution.