# storing input from stdin into list

Tags: c, list, input, struct, stdin

I'm going to be getting input in the following format and I wish to store it into an arraylist or maybe even a linked list (whichever one is easier to implement):

`3,5;6,7;8,9;11,4;`

I want to be able to put the two numbers before the `;` into a structure and store these. For example, I want 3,5 to be grouped together, and 6,7 to be grouped together.

I'm unsure as to how to read the input and obtain each pair and store it. The input I'm going to get can be fairly large (up to 60-70mB).

I have tried to use `strtok()` and `strtol()` however I just can't seem to get the correct implementation.

Any help would be great

EDIT:

What I have tried to do up til now is use this piece of code to read the input:

```
char[1000] remainder;
int first, second;
fp = fopen("C:\\file.txt", "r"); // Error check this, probably.
while (fgets(&remainder, 1000, fp) != null) { // Get a line.
    while (sscanf(remainder, "%d,%d;%s", first, second, remainder) != null) {
        // place first and second into a struct or something
    }
}
```

I fixed the syntax errors in the code, but when I try and compile, it crashes.

Comment: Did you not ask a similar question few minutes back? What happened?

Comment: To save confusion and many more edits, I just decided to ask a new question describing the problem as precisely as I could in this q

Comment: Then you should have known `I have tried to use` is not good enough. Don't edit out the required part to achieve `describing the problem as precisely as I could in this q`.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to convey, but thanks for the input.

Comment: Don't thank unless you understood what i'm trying to say, there's no point in doing so. :-) What i tried to mean is show us your code and tell us where/why/how did it fail. Then only we'll be able to help you. We cannot produce some solution to your problem out of thin air, right?

Comment: Do keep in mind that i'm a beginner, so I may well have missed something trivial

Comment: I don't know what you didn't like about the previous answers to your question. The only new requirement here is that you group 1,2 and 3,4, etc.. The answer to this question the last time you asked it works perfectly fine here to. Once you have the numbers in an array, then grouping is a simple odd/even match beginning at 0. The original question/answer is here [**reading large lists through stdin in C**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135956/reading-large-lists-through-stdin-in-c/29137699?noredirect=1#comment46551044_29137699)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the addition of a single line, the same answer provides a robust and flexible solution to your problem. Take the time to understand what it does. It is not complicated at all, it is simply basic C. In order for you to do your conversion from `string` to `int`, you have 2 choices provided by **libc**, `atoi` (no error checking) and `strtol` (with error checking). Your only other alternative is to code a conversion by hand, which given your comments in both versions of this question, isn't what you are looking for.

The following is a good solution. Take the time to learn what it does. Regardless whether you use `fgets` or `getline`, the approach to the problem is the same. Let me know what your questions are:

```
/* read unliminted number of int values into array from stdin
(semicolon or comma separated values, pair every 2 values)
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define NMAX 256

int main () {

    char *ln = NULL;                /* NULL forces getline to allocate  */
    size_t n = 0;                   /* max chars to read (0 - no limit) */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;               /* number of chars actually read    */
    int *numbers = NULL;            /* array to hold numbers            */
    size_t nmax = NMAX;             /* check for reallocation           */
    size_t idx = 0;                 /* numbers array index              */

    if (!(numbers = calloc (NMAX, sizeof *numbers))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line from stdin - dynamicallly allocated   */
    while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        char *p = ln;       /* pointer for use with strtol  */
        char *ep = NULL;

        errno = 0;
        while (errno == 0)
        {
            /* parse/convert each number on stdin   */
            numbers[idx] = strtol (p, &ep, 10);
            /* note: overflow/underflow checks omitted */
            /* if valid conversion to number */
            if (errno == 0 && p != ep)
            {
                idx++;              /* increment index      */
                if (!ep) break;     /* check for end of str */
            }

            /* skip delimiters/move pointer to next digit   */
            while (*ep && (*ep <= '0' || *ep >= '9')) ep++;
            if (*ep)
                p = ep;
            else
                break;

            /* reallocate numbers if idx = nmax */
            if (idx == nmax)
            {
                int *tmp = realloc (numbers, 2 * nmax * sizeof *numbers);
                if (!tmp) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "Error: struct reallocation failure.\n");
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                numbers = tmp;
                memset (numbers + nmax, 0, nmax * sizeof *numbers);
                nmax *= 2;
            }
        }
    }

    /* free mem allocated by getline */
    if (ln) free (ln);

    /* show values stored in array   */
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        if ( i % 2 == 1 )       /* pair ever 2 values */
            printf (" numbers[%2zu] numbers[%2zu]  %d, %d\n", i-1, i, numbers[i-1], numbers[i]);

    /* free mem allocated to numbers  */
    if (numbers) free (numbers);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ echo "3,5;6,7;8,9;11,4;;" | ./bin/parsestdin2
 numbers[ 0] numbers[ 1]  3, 5
 numbers[ 2] numbers[ 3]  6, 7
 numbers[ 4] numbers[ 5]  8, 11
```

Comment: Why does the array to hold the numbers start off as NULL? And looking at the code above, is the growth factor of the array 2?

Comment: also, can you explain this condition in more detail? I can't wrap my head around it `while (*ep && (*ep <= '0' || *ep >= '9')) ep++;`

Comment: Sure, that is just says skip over everything that is not between `ASCII 0 and 9` until you get to the next digit or end of string. You only want to collect numbers, not punctuation, etc... This is how it skips the `;` When you have a character pointer, say `ep`, it holds the address where it points in memory. Dereferencing the pointer `*ep` returns the value (the character) at that address. So `*ep` is just the individual character at that address, and `ep++` moves to the next (e.g. increases the memory address so it points to the next character) At the end of the string, `*ep = 0` (null)

Comment: @cp101020304 - Excellent, I am glad to see you taking the time to learn. This is great code to learn, as it contains the foundation principals of C. It isn't easy, it takes work, but if you take the time to understand this code, you will have accomplished a great deal as far as understanding pointers, pointer arithmetic, memory allocation/reallocation, etc.. Keep working, nothing comes for free, and anything worth having is worth working for.

Comment: @cp101020304 - you always want to initialize all your variables/arrays. For integer or character arrays, initializing to '0' (NULL) insures your strings are always `null-terminated` and prevents you from attempting to reference uninitialized values (the bane of new C programmers). So **always initialize your variables (and memory)**. It will make your life **much** easier.

Comment: @cp101020304 `while (*ep && (*ep <= '0' || *ep >= '9')) ep++;` literally says while `*ep != 0` (end of string) **AND** the current character is `<= ASCII 48` (the 0 digit) **OR** the current character is `>= ASCII 57` (the 9 digit), then `ep++` (move to the next character in the string).` See: [**ASCII Table and Description**](http://www.asciitable.com/) . Sorry I mistyped `43` instead of `48` in the earlier comment.